# Getting a specific control from a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to programatically go through a window's child elements to find one with a certain name? I'm loading xaml dynamically that creates a window and I'm looking to find a "placeholder" control inside it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the root control's FindName method.

Comment: Because controls are added programatically don't forget to use  RegisterName.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1faeed04-3adf-4324-9a1b-68ac4aca64bc

Comment: Yep, this is a very important step thats usuaully overlooked. Simply giving it a name is not enough.

Comment: Considering that my window is built through XamlReader.LoadAsync, I don't need to register anything. So FindName just works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
VisualTreeHelper
```

to enumerate down the tree of controls.